# How to add EOFB (End of facsimile block) in tif image

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a tif image with CCIT4 compression. This image is not having EOFB. Could someone help me how to add this EOFB to the tif image. Or how to create an image with EOFB information.

Here is my code that generate image without EOFB

```
 var tifImg = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        tifImg.SetResolution(200, 200);
        Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(tifImg);
        graphic.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500));
        try
        {

                string data = "My data"; 
                Font vrFont = new Font("Verdana", 32, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                Size micrSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(data, vrFont); 
                graphic.DrawString(data, vrFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(10, 100)); 
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20, 200, 60);
                graphic.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black)), rectangle);
                SaveImage(tifImg, fileName, appLogger);


        var imageEncoders = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().ToList();
        var imageCodecInfo = imageEncoders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.MimeType == "image/tiff");

        var encoderParameter = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(2);
        encoderParameter.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
        encoderParameter.Param[1] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)18);

            tifImg.Save(fileName, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameter); 
        }
        catch { throw; }
        finally
        {
            graphic.Dispose();
            tifImg.Dispose();
        }
```

Thanks,

Esen

Comment: we need to see the code.

Comment: @Hogan I have added my code as suggested.

Comment: I'm no good at this sort of thing, but I feel like this might be of help: http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm  Search for EOFB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I did in my project. Check if this help you.

```
 private void AddEOFB(string imgFileName)
    {
        var fs = new FileStream(imgFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        try
        {
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            var buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x00100100);
            fs.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }
        catch { throw; }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i know you want c# but see [this class](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/6.0-JDK-Modules/Java-Advanced-Imaging/com/sun/media/jai/codecimpl/TIFFFaxEncoder.java.htm) in java language and search all *"addEOFB"*.